# Questions on how to upload a file to a specific branch (GIT)

Tags: bash, git, github, git-bash

I'm taking a course in CS50 and I need to submit a file for evaluation on GitHub.
The instruction is as follows:

If you've installed `submit50`, execute

```
submit50 ai50/projects/2020/x/knights
```

Otherwise, using Git, push your work to https://github.com/me50/USERNAME.git, where USERNAME is your GitHub username, on a branch called ai50/projects/2020/x/knights.

However, I tried using submit50 directly from Git Bash, but I encountered the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'
```

I also couldn't fix this error.
I tried following the path of creating a branch and pushing the file, but when I try to do that through the command line in Git Bash, my entire local repository gets pushed.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

The problem seems simple, but I'm running and running using commands in Git without success... There came a point where I had to delete my local repository and clone my personal remote repository again to reorganize my workspace. The objective is simply to send a .py file to a branch called ai50/projects/2020/x/knights.

Comment: `submit50` is not a Git command, that's not a Git error message. Open up the command and see what language it's written in, the message looks like a python message, and install the missing module.

Comment: @jthill from what I understand Submit50 is a module. I installed using pip install. However, when I used the command the second error appeared. I tried to install 'termios' and I couldn't.

Comment: https://github.com/cs50/submit50/issues?q=is%3Aissue+termios You cannot run the command on Windows. You can run it in WLS. Not sure about Git-Bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by copying my entire repository to a specific branch and then removing the unwanted files. However, I still have doubts about how to create a new branch in another remote repository from my local repository, keeping only a specific file instead of the entire content of the current repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to push one file, add that file using `git add {file name}`, commit it with `git commit -m "commit message"`, and push it with `git push` (or, if you do not have your local repo hooked up to your github one, do `git remote origin {the URL to your repo}.git` and then `git push -u origin {your branch}`)

Comment: Hello,
I tried to do that and it didn't work.
I actually first created a branch from the command line.
When I try to use git add {file} and then commit -m {comment} it says I have nothing to update in my repository. The idea is to send this file from my personal repository to another repository according to the guidelines presented in the task.

Comment: If it says that, your file is already on github. If you have other files on github you would like to remove, you can manually delete them from github.